# How to get the print as PDF result using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I would like to get the HTML page in the PDF.

After some studies I found the pdfJS plugin, it has some problem with bootstrap , the layout will be messy

http://jsfiddle.net/5ud8jkvf/

here is the fiddle

I found the default print as PDF result is great

[image]

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```

So , instead of fixing the problem for pdfJS, I wonder are there html / jquery way to get the pdf from the print as pdf.

The HTML need to convert to PDF is one page application form only, thanks a lot

Comment: any progress? I am also in need of same requirement

Comment: Can you include `html` at image at Question?

Comment: @user782104 can you specify which issue you are facing with bootstrap and jstopdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version allows to get the [blob](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.js#L970) or the [arraybuffer](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/jspdf.js#L968) of the pdf. The only thing you have to do is to update from 0.9 to 1.2.x of the library and call save like this

```
var myBlob;

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    myBlob = doc.save('blob');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you can try html2canvas(It will parse the DOM, Calculate the styles applied).

```
(function(){
var 
 form = $('.form'),
 cache_width = form.width(),
 a4  =[ 595.28,  841.89];  // for a4 size paper width and height

$('#create_pdf').on('click',function(){
 $('body').scrollTop(0);
 createPDF();
});
//create pdf
function createPDF(){
 getCanvas().then(function(canvas){
  var 
  img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
  doc = new jsPDF({
          unit:'px', 
          format:'a4'
        });     
        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
        doc.save('techumber-html-to-pdf.pdf');
        form.width(cache_width);
 });
}

// create canvas object
function getCanvas(){
 form.width((a4[0]*1.33333) -80).css('max-width','none');
 return html2canvas(form,{
     imageTimeout:2000,
     removeContainer:true
    }); 
}

}());
```

I found this [here](http://www.techumber.com/2015/04/html-to-pdf-conversion-using-javascript.html). Please check the link if you want more info.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to print table data into PDF Format.So you can use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) jQuery Plugin.

Datatables provide [button](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) library in which you can use `PDF` button.
Its support both HTML5 and Flash and button type automatically select between the Flash and HTML button options.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
buttons: [
    'pdf'
]
} );
```

Its provide excel export feature too, you just need to add `excel` button.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
buttons: [
    'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
]
} );
```

I have already used in our application it will not make any conflict with bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Try [jsPDF-AutoTable (jsPDF plugin)](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable), this may help you to convert to PDF from HTML as you want. Check out the [demo](https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable/)